# Full time software developer considering taking a part time lecturer at a college looking for advice on how to proceed

Tags: software-industry, employer-relations, company-policy, employment-agreement

I am a full time software developer at a large company lets call it BigCompany (not the real name) and I would like to teach a few hours of computer science courses on the weekend at a community college total hours per month about 20.

The company that I work for  BigCompany requires I disclose any outside business interests.

I would like to do the teaching because Ive done it before also while working a fulltime job elsewhere, I found it really fun, good way to practice my presentation skills and a good way to motivate me to code in my spare time.

Again all the hours would be on the weekend non business hours and it wouldn't be more than 20 Hours a month total. I know the dean and he is very flexible . If I had a work priority at BigCompany could easily get a replacement to teach that day at the college.

It is a small college so I dont see why it would be a conflict of interest or why they should be concerned with me doing it.

Sometimes at BigCompany I do have to do support outside of business hours but I dont think it will conflict with my teaching schedule.

I have been with the BigCompany about 5 months , am off probation and I did speak with HR and they didnt think this would be an issue.

Any thoughts or issues please let me know.

Comment: None left - you seem to have covered them... So up to you to make the decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that being in the classroom giving the lecture is only one part of the job, actually thinking trough what to teach, preparing the materials and exercises, grading exams, etc.. can take up even more time, make sure this work does not creep too much into your regular workdays, otherwise you'll end up dropping balls, and or burning out.

Comment: In addition, as a part-time employee for a school, odds are bad you'll get converted into a full time, and odds are even worse you'll get paid a reasonable wage for the additional hours of preparation, lesson plan development, and actual time giving the lectures.  This is why long-term professors tend to give the same lectures, they wouldn't have time to do anything else if they had to draft them fresh each time.  If you're getting paid 20 hours by the school, I'd set aside 40 hours for the actual work (until you have your lecture "canned")